# Google Doc image issue using Workato message templates

Tags: html, image, doc, workato

I used Workato to create google doc using their message template. The message template is written in HTML and Workato also use mustache code for their message templates. Successfully for six months (up to Dec 1st) the code would create the document and also display a logo image that was linked. Periodically I noticed this issue happening in November where the logo image wouldn't load properly in the file.

Since Dec 1 we can't make the logo appear in the document. I have worked with the engineering team at Workato and have determined using Postman that the logo image link and document template is fine.

Is there an issue on how a google doc displays images through an API that would have changed on or around Dec 1st?